# Needs to pass the value based if the value has only one group when grouping is applied in xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

Can you please help me how the below logic can we archived using XSLT

in the below input in the goodsHolders segments, we have different goodsHolderItems with 2 different deliverynotenumber so in this case no need to add netweight and grossweight

in the case 2 input payload there are goodsHolders segment with same deliverynotenumber in the goodsHolderItems so in this case we need to add netweight and gross weight

Input:
`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <multimap:Message1>
        <VM/>
    </multimap:Message1>
    <multimap:Message2>
        <root>
            <event/>
            <notification>
                <goodsHolders>
                    <goodsHolderMeasures>
                        <netWeight>
                            <measureValue>6.45</measureValue>
                            <measureUOM>KG</measureUOM>
                        </netWeight>
                        <grossWeight>
                            <measureValue>6.45</measureValue>
                            <measureUOM>KG</measureUOM>
                        </grossWeight>
                    </goodsHolderMeasures>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>123</deliveryNoteNumber>
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>123</deliveryNoteNumber>
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>456</deliveryNoteNumber>
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>456</deliveryNoteNumber>
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                </goodsHolders>
            </notification>
        </root>
    </multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <multimap:Message1>
        <VM/>
    </multimap:Message1>
    <multimap:Message2>
        <root>
            <event/>
            <notification>
                <goodsHolders>
                    <goodsHolderMeasures>
                        
                    </goodsHolderMeasures>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>123</deliveryNoteNumber>
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>123</deliveryNoteNumber>
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>456</deliveryNoteNumber>
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>456</deliveryNoteNumber>
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                </goodsHolders>
            </notification>
        </root>
    </multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
```

Case 2:
Input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <multimap:Message1>
        <VM/>
    </multimap:Message1>
    <multimap:Message2>
        <root>
            <event/>
            <notification>
                <goodsHolders>
                    <goodsHolderMeasures>
                        <netWeight>
                            <measureValue>6.45</measureValue>
                            <measureUOM>KG</measureUOM>
                        </netWeight>
                        <grossWeight>
                            <measureValue>6.45</measureValue>
                            <measureUOM>KG</measureUOM>
                        </grossWeight>
                    </goodsHolderMeasures>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>123</deliveryNoteNumber>
                        
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                </goodsHolders>
                <goodsHolders>
                    <goodsHolderMeasures>
                        <netWeight>
                            <measureValue>6.45</measureValue>
                            <measureUOM>KG</measureUOM>
                        </netWeight>
                        <grossWeight>
                            <measureValue>6.45</measureValue>
                            <measureUOM>KG</measureUOM>
                        </grossWeight>
                    </goodsHolderMeasures>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>123</deliveryNoteNumber>
                    
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                </goodsHolders>
            </notification>
        </root>
    </multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <multimap:Message1>
        <VM/>
    </multimap:Message1>
    <multimap:Message2>
        <root>
            <event/>
            <notification>
                <goodsHolders>
                    <goodsHolderMeasures>
                        <netWeight>
                            <measureValue>12.9</measureValue>
                            <measureUOM>KG</measureUOM>
                        </netWeight>
                        <grossWeight>
                            <measureValue>12.9</measureValue>
                            <measureUOM>KG</measureUOM>
                        </grossWeight>
                    </goodsHolderMeasures>
                    <goodsHolderItems>
                        <deliveryNoteNumber>123</deliveryNoteNumber>
                        
                    </goodsHolderItems>
                </goodsHolders>
        
            </notification>
        </root>
    </multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
```

Comment: i think the question is too complex, best write 2 or more simple questions with simple examples.